# T-SQL: Conditional sorting on two columns

Tags: t-sql, sorting

I have a table, TableA, that looks like this:

```
ColA    ColB
0        20
1        10
0        5
1        15
```

I want to sort the rows so that all the records where ColA = 0 are listed first, and then these records are sorted by ColB ascendingly. After all the rows with ColA = 0 are listed, I then want to list all the rows with ColA = 1 but these rows sorted by ColB descendingly.

The results should look like this:

```
ColA    ColB
0        5
0        20
1        15
1        10
```

Is this possible? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select t.ColA, t.ColB
from t
order by t.ColA
   ,case when t.ColA = 0 then t.ColB end asc
   ,case when t.ColA = 1 then t.ColB end desc
```

Comment: Thanks a million. Wasn't aware that case statements could be used in the order clause. Learning something new every day.

Comment: Actually, I couldn't apply this pattern to SQL Server 2008.

Comment: Sorry, I tested again: actually the problem is just a mistyped extra comma in your code (after `t.ColA` and before `case` there are two commas.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ColA,ColB
FROM table
ORDER BY 
 ColA, (CASE WHEN ColA = 1 THEN -1 * ColB ELSE ColB END)
```

Comment: Definitely a shorter solution than oryol's but multiplication will probably have a performance hit.